# Showing that the following functions aren't inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Show that the following functions aren't inner products:
>
> $$1. \ V=\mathbb R_5[x];\    \ \langle p,q\rangle =\sum^5_{i=0}p(q(i))
> \\2. \ V=\mathcal M_{2\times2}(\mathbb R);\    \ \langle A,B\rangle =\det(A^\top B) $$

For 1. I'm not sure how to formally write it but if we take say $p $ to be some 'negative' polynomial like: $-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5$ the sum will be negative thus it won't satisfy the axiom.

Another way would be to say that a composition isn't the same both ways.

For 2. we know that the determinant can be a negative number so if $A=1, \ B=-1$ (those are 1 by 1 matrices) we get a negative product so it doesn't satisfy the axiom.

Comment: Inner products can be negative, it's just $<p,p>$ has to be positive for $p\not = 0$. The second argument for (1) is correct though (not symmetric). For 2, look at linearity, or look at $<A,A>$ for a matrix with $det(A)=0$

Comment: Isn't what $<p,p>$ equal to supposed to be positive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For $1$.** 
Let be $$p=x^2 \text{ and } q=-x^2$$ 
Then $$p(q(x)) = -x^4 \text{ and } g(p(x))=x^2$$
Thus $$p\cdot q < 0 \text{ but } q\cdot p >0$$

---

**For $2$.** 
Let $$A_1 = B = \mathcal{I}_2 = -A_2 $$

Now note that
$$(A_1+A_2)\cdot B = 0 \cdot B = 0 \neq 2 = A_1\cdot B + A_2\cdot B$$

---

( *Remark*: I wrote "$\cdot$" for the *inner product* )

Comment: Thanks. I think you meant to say that $A_2=-I$ so I'm kinda confused about how the RHS equal to 2...

Comment: If $A_2=-I_2$ and $B=I_2$ then $A_2^TB= -I_2$, thus $\det A_2^TB = 1$

Comment: And yes, there has been a typo in my answer. Of course it should be $A_2 = -I_2$. I corrected it.